# Delete row for a condition of other row values

Tags: python, pandas

|  | group_id | cust_id | score | x1 | x2 | contract_id | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 101 | 1 | 95 | F | 30 | 1 | 30 |
| 1 | 101 | 1 | 95 | F | 30 | 2 | 26 |
| 2 | 101 | 2 | 85 | M | 28 | 1 | 8 |
| 3 | 101 | 2 | 85 | M | 28 | 2 | 18 |

I want to delete rows with the same cust_id but the smaller y values. For example, for cust_id=1, I want to delete row with index =1.

I am thinking using df.loc to select rows with same cust_id and then drop them by the condition of comparing the column y. But I don't know how to do the first part.

Comment: If you just want the max row, group by your customer ID then keep only the row with the max. `df[df.groupby('id')['y'].idxmax()]`

Comment: @ifly6. Don't forget `.loc`: `df.loc[df.groupby('cust_id')['y'].idxmax()]`

Comment: @ifly6. I added your suggestion to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76009218/15239951). If you decide to post your own answer, let me know, I will remove my update.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to sort by `y` the use [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to keep only one occurrence of each `cust_id`:

```
out = df.sort_values('y', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('cust_id')
print(out)

# Output
   group_id  cust_id  score x1  x2  contract_id   y
0       101        1     95  F  30            1  30
3       101        2     85  M  28            2  18
```

As suggested by [@ifly6](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2741091/ifly6), you can use [`groupby_idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
out = df.loc[df.groupby('cust_id')['y'].idxmax()]
print(out)

# Output
   group_id  cust_id  score x1  x2  contract_id   y
0       101        1     95  F  30            1  30
3       101        2     85  M  28            2  18
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop_duplicates`. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
# Some data
df = pd.DataFrame({'cust_id': [1, 2, 1, 3, 4], 'y': [3, 4, 1, 5, 7]})
# Sorting by cust_id is actually not necessary
df.sort_values(by=['cust_id', 'y'], ascending=[True, True], inplace=True)
# Remove all the duplicates by cust_id, keeping the first one found
df.drop_duplicates(subset='cust_id', keep='last', inplace=True)

print(df)

    cust_id y
0   1   3
1   2   4
3   3   5
4   4   7
```